# x86 real mode segmentation in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, real-mode

In real mode, the memory locations are often accessed using segment:offset addressing. The physical location is calculated as :

```
physical address = segment address * 16 + offset
```

However, I need little help understanding the below code taken from [here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/master/real_segmentation.S)

```
#include "common.h"
BEGIN
    CLEAR

    /* It is not possible to encode moving immediates
     * to segment registers: we must either:
     *
     * * pass through a general register ax
     * * pop from the stack
     */
    mov $1, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ds:msg, %al
    PUTC <%al>

    /* %ds is the default segment for GAS memory operations
     * if we don't write it explicitly.
     */
    mov msg, %al
    PUTC <%al>

    hlt
msg:
    /* Push the correct A forward 16 bytes in memory
     * to compensate for the segments.
     */
    .fill 0x10
    .byte 'A'
```

1. How does `%ds:msg` is evaluated? Do we do %ds + address of msg ? Why we need 1 in %ds ?
2. "Push the correct A forward 16 bytes in memory to compensate for segments" what compensation is being talked here?

Please help.

Comment: The author is only demonstrating segmentation. By putting 1 in DS (Rather than 0) he's advancing the physical memory address by 16 bytes (1<<4)=16. As ane experiment  they pad 0x10(16) bytes with `.fill 0x10` addressing the `A` with ds:msg. IT is a real dumb example to show how segmentation works. I can see how it could be confusing.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Thanks. And how does `%ds:msg` get evaluated?

Comment: LIke any other segment:offset pair. DS:msg would be 0x0001:msg which is (1<<4)+(offset of msg) (1<<4 is same as multiplying by 16)

Comment: I recommend reading: https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html

Comment: 'msg' will be replaced by VMA of msg during above calculation?

Comment: Yes it will InsaneCoder